# Why does the Matter Anti-Matter imbalance require breaking CP symmetry? Why can't it occur if time symmetry is broken?

Tags: particle-physics, big-bang, antimatter

I understand the general argument that, without some breaking of symmetry, all the matter in the universe would annihilate all the anti-matter and we'd be left with nothing but photons and some other relativistic particles. I've read several posts and articles claiming there must be a broken CP symmetry somewhere for a small fraction of baryons to be left over. I have never seen any discussion of why a broken time symmetry couldn't result in the same imbalance.

Let's say, for the sake of argument, that every second was shorter than the second that came before by a teeny-tiny amount. Is there an argument to be made in particle physics that the deceleration of time can favor one form of matter over the other?

Answer (score 3):

Let's define our terms, just to make sure we are talking about the same thing.

In a Lorentz-invariant model, where your system is unchanged under rotations and boosts, there are three discrete transformations that you can make mathematically which leave your system unchanged if applied an even number of times.  These are charge conjugation (C), where you reverse the signs of all the charge quantum numbers of a system; parity inversion (P), where you switch between right- and left-handed coordinate systems; and time reversal (T), where you reverse the direction of the flow of time.

The combined transformation CP, where you conjugate all of the charge quantum numbers and reverse the parity of a system, is the transformation which takes a matter field into its antimatter counterpart and vice-versa.  If you want your model to treat matter and antimatter differently, for instance by ending up with a matter excess when starting from a hot vacuum, then your model must include CP violation.

Lorentz invariance requires that CPT is an exact symmetry. In a Lorentz-invariant model, such as the standard model of particle physics, CP violation and T violation are two sides of the same coin.  Ten years ago I could have rattled off a list of a half-dozen current or recent T-violation experiments, but I'm no longer connected to the literature.

Note that CPT invariance is also an experimental question, but we have no reason to doubt it so far (apart from a healthy dose of innate skepticism).

---

In comments, you write

> According to Lorentz invariance, there should be nothing here but photons.

which is a misunderstanding. Symmetry under rotations and boosts allows CP violation.  It just requires an equal amount of T violation, to preserve symmetry under the combined transformation CPT.

You also comment on a number of "failures of general relativity" on galactic and cosmological length scales.  But note that the standard model takes place in a flat spacetime, where general relativity reduces to special relativity.  We don't have a quantum-mechanical field theory on a strongly curved spacetime.

Comment: I don't understand why you would bring up Lorentz invariance. According to Lorentz invariance, there should be nothing here but photons. Clearly, we know Lorentz Invariance is wrong. The only question is which of the CPT assumptions was broken to allow matter to be produced in greater quantities than anti-matter. It would be great if you had some insight into that question.

Comment: That's not correct. The transformation CP (conjugating all charge quantum numbers, and reversing parity) is the transformation which sends a matter field to an antimatter field. It is CP-invariant theories which predict equal amounts of matter and antimatter. Lorentz invariance, the bedrock of relativity, says that CP invariance is the same as T invariance, because Lorentz invariance requires CPT as an exact symmetry.

Comment: I don't understand why you think this is relevant. #1 *"It is CP-invariant theories which predict equal amounts of matter and antimatter"* You're just restating the problem. We know this, we also know you need to break a symmetry to have matter left over after the annihilation. #2 *"Lorentz invariance, the bedrock of relativity"* The list of GRs failures is long. It failed to predict galaxy rotation curves, the Tully-Fisher relation, the accelerated expansion of the universe and the homogeneity of background radiation. Why do you think Lorentz Invariance's failure in GR is some sort of proof?

Comment: We seem to be talking past each other a little bit, so I have expanded the answer.